# why there is missing keyword error in argument

Tags: python

compiler show the missing keyword argument for prime(list,num) but i think i do this correctly *arg for list and n for num.
But why there is show keyword argument error for print(list,num)

```
num = int(input('Please enter a number : '))
list = [i for i in range(2,int((num/2) +1))]

def prime(*arg , n):
    for test in arg:
        if n % test == 0 :
             print('%d number is not a prime number.' %n)
        elif n == 1 or n == 0:
             print('Number is bellow 2.')
        else :
             print('It is a prime number')

prime(list, num)
```

[image]

Comment: **"Why is this happening to me?"** "Why is what happening to you?" **"This error"** "What error?"

Comment: Please post the relevant part of your code that gave you the error mentioned and then state precisely what the error is and what you have done to solve it

Comment: `*args` can only be followed by keyword arguments or `**kwargs`, not a positional argument. And the highlighting of `list` gives you an hint that that name belongs to Python (builtin list).

Comment: unrelated to the error issue, you dont have to go up until `int((num/2) +1)` (which btw you can write as `num // 2 + 1`) but up until the root of num `int(num**0.5)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntactically, **keyword-only** arguments are coded as named arguments that may appear after `*arg` in the arguments list. All such arguments must be passed using keyword syntax in the call.

For example, in the following, `a` may be passed by name or position,
`b` collects any extra positional arguments, and `c` must be passed by keyword only.

```
>>> def kwonly(a, *b, c):
        print(a, b, c)

>>>>kwonly(1, 2, c=3)
1 (2,) 3

>>>kwonly(1, 2, 3)
TypeError: kwonly() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'c'
```

So you must pass `n` as as keyword argument only.

```
def prime(*arg , n):
```

`n` must be passed by keyword-only value

```
prime(list, n=num)
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `*` from the `arg` parameter

```
def prime(arg, n):
    # rest of code here
```

Comment: thnx but is not i use *arg for pass the value  list/tuple as argument? @smac89

Comment: @Tuhin, you don't need `*` to pass arguments as lists/tuples